# Run JavaScript in Fancybox Modal Window (Use .on() to sort table columns)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fancybox

I'm a novice programmer with a basic grasp of JS and JQuery. I am using Fancybox to pull an HTML Table via Ajax and show it to users of our system.

**HTML (within Fancybox):**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="priority-2 sortable date" style="min-width:150px">Date / Time</th>
            <th class="priority-2 sortable text" style="min-width:150px">Changed By</th>
            <th class="priority-1 sortable text" style="min-width:150px">Previous Value</th>
            <th class="priority-1 sortable text" style="min-width:150px">New Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="priority-2">15/12/2021 11:23</td>
            <td class="priority-2">John Smith</td>
            <td class="priority-1">Stalled</td>
            <td class="priority-1">Test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="priority-2">14/12/2021 16:58</td>
            <td class="priority-2">David Jones</td>
            <td class="priority-1">Live</td>
            <td class="priority-1">Stalled</td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I have some Javascript that I use elsewhere to sort tables when the  is clicked which works OK. I know that to get this to work on Ajax content I have to change the .click() to use .on() but with my my limited knowledge I cannot get the syntax to work correctly.

**JS (in seperate .js file):**

*Original Code:*

```
$('thead th.sortable').each(function(index, listItem) {

    $(this).click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        // sort column code here

    });
});
```

*My attempt at amending the code:*

```
$('thead th.sortable').each(function(index, listItem) {

    $(this).on('click', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        // sort column code here

    });
});
```

I have tried using $(document).(this) etc. but to no avail. The above works in the main HTML but not in the Fancybox window.

I use the following JS Code to show/hide sections which I've successfully adapted to work in the Fancybox window:

```
$(document).on('click', '.header-row', function(e) {

    // Toggle Section code here

});
```

Any help with the syntax I need is appreciated. Apologies in advance for the poor coding knowledge.

Comment: Please, create a demo using any code playground - jsfiddle, codesanbox, etc.

Comment: I've created a pen here, but this doesn't use Fancybox and the JS doesn't seem to work:

https://codepen.io/Mav3000/pen/BawqGjN?editors=1010

Comment: But why did you not include Fancybox? Just use CDN links.

Comment: I've updated the codepen with Fancybox included, however I'm unable to get fancybox to show the table (sorry about this - I've never used codepen before).

Comment: `<a href="#" data-fancybox data-source="#test">Click Here to Open Fancybox</a>` - it will not work, Fancybox does not support `data-source` attribute.

Comment: Codepen corrected (Fancybox now opens correctly, but table columns are not sortable):

https://codepen.io/Mav3000/pen/BawqGjN?editors=1010

Comment: Now you have `Uncaught ReferenceError: getLowestChildElement is not defined` error in your code.

Comment: Hi Janis, Pen updated. JS now works (tables are sorting when column headers are clicked). Issue is that the JS does not work if the FancyBox is loaded via Ajax.

I open FB with the following code:

<a data-fancybox="" data-type="ajax" data-src="ajax.php?func=get_modal_data">

Comment: Now your code runs fine. You probably have to run your JS code after Fancybox has loaded the content (E.g., when it exists in the DOM)

Comment: Yes that is the problem. How can I get the JS code to work in the Fancybox is the JS code exists before the FB content? I can't move the JS code from its .JS file into the FB content HTML. Using .on("click" works for my other functions but I'm not sure of the syntax to use to get this working for this particular function (I'm not a JS expert).

Comment: You do not need to be JS expert to use Fancybox events - https://fancyapps.com/docs/ui/fancybox/events - just execute your code when load or done event is fired.